# Black displayng with VideoView into Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-videoview

i have a problem with the VideoView.
I have a videoView and an ImageView, when i try to display a video i set invisible the ImageView and visible the videoView. Also i correctly put the URI to the VideoView but it doesn't show me the video... this is my simple code

```
videoView = (VideoView) getView().findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
slidingimage = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
slidingimage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(singletonMedia.listaMedia.get(currentMedia).url);
//Log.w(null, "URI del video: "+vidUri);
videoView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
videoView.start();
Log.w(null, "Media corrente: " + currentMedia+ " Questo e' un video con uri:"+vidUri);
```

Can onyone help me pease, thanks in advance

Comment: post your logcat and also check URI objecty

Comment: i have done this and the uri is correct...

Comment: what happen if you only show the videoview and remove the imageview? I need to know this to make sure your videoview run well

Comment: it gives me black display ... in other parts of code i hidden the VideoView and show the ImageView and it work fine... so i think that should be the same if i hide ImageView and show VideoView..,

Answer (score 0):

Add this Right before videoView.start():

```
videoView.requestFocus();
```